# magento 2 execute 2 events in 1 observer

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

I create **2 events in 1 observer** & I tried to execute them in 1 time but it just display error. How to solve it ? Is there any solution ?

**=> Event :**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="customprice" instance="Test\Show\Observer\CustomPrice" />
  </event>
  <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
    <observer name="loadupdate" instance="Test\Show\Observer\CustomPrice" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**=> Observer :**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        //event for change price when product added to cart
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $price = $item->getProduct()->getPrice() - 800;
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

        //event for change product price when product data loaded
        $collections = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        foreach( $collections as $collection ) {
            $collection->setPrice(25000);
            $collection->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: When i tried to add a product to the cart, there is a warning "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."

Comment: have you checked log ? Also add the magento version you are using to question